# iOS app for simple battery statistics

Tags: ios, iphone-app, battery

I'm looking for an app that shows/calculates:

- time since last charging*
- average time between charging
- average charging time

Optionally:

- graph history of battery level
- charging current

Note: all above is a about stored electricity and not battery wear, capacity changes etc.

The app store is full of battery apps, but none I found had the above features (and they have a lot of what I don't need).

* The iOS Settings/Battery shows "Time since last full charge" in two parts: *Usage* and *Standby*. To get total time, do I add them? Or is the second the total time and the first a part of it?

*Edit:*

About "Time since last full charge" : apparently (I observed the values for a few hours on an iPhone) the *Standby* value is "total time". At least in iOS 11.0.